# TextBox OnTextChanged in Gridview does not store value into list

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dictionary, textbox

I am trying to implement when textbox in gridView onTextChanged, it will autoPostBack to check whether the storage level is sufficient. I set up my gridView using repeater and collapsible panel extender. If it is sufficient, it will store into an array. Then, when the button on click, it will loop thru the array and perform insert Sql statement. Here is how I set up my gridView:

```
<!-- Collapsible panel extender body -->
                        <asp:Panel ID="pBody1" runat="server" CssClass="cpBody">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblBodyText1" runat="server" />
                            <!-- Grid view to show products based on each category -->
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvProduct" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="998px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" DataKeyNames="id">
                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbCheckRow" runat="server" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>                               
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="650px" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="inventoryQuantity" HeaderText="Total Unit" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbQuantity" runat="server" Width="60" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "unitQuantity") %>' OnTextChanged="tbQuantity_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCheckAmount" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </asp:Panel>
```

When textBox OnTextChanged method, it will get the prodID and textBox value which is quantity from selected row then loop it to perform check. If it is insufficient, I display the error message using a label:

```
    //Dictionary used to pair up prodID and quantity
    Dictionary<string, string> tempList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Dictionary<string, string> distSPUItemList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    protected void tbQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string quantity = "", prodID = "";
        int packagesNeeded = 0, totalUnit = 0;

        //Get the total packages needed for this distribution
        packagesNeeded = prodPackBLL.getPackagesNeededByDistributionID(distributionID);

        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                Panel pnl = item.FindControl("pBody1") as Panel;
                GridView gv = pnl.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
                foreach (GridViewRow gr in gv.Rows)
                {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("cbCheckRow");
                    if (cb.Checked)
                    {
                        //Clear label error message
                        Label lblCheckAmount = gr.FindControl("lblCheckAmount") as Label;
                        lblCheckAmount.Text = "";

                        //Get the productID which set as DataKeyNames and unit quantity from selected row index
                        prodID = gv.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

                        var tbQuantity = gr.FindControl("tbQuantity") as TextBox;
                        if (tbQuantity != null)
                        {
                            quantity = tbQuantity.Text;
                        }

                        //Add both objects into Dictionary
                        tempList.Add(prodID, quantity);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Loop thru tempList. key as prodID, tempList.Keys as quantity
        foreach (string key in tempList.Keys)
        {
            //Get total unit of each products
            totalUnit = prodPackBLL.getTotalProductUnit(key);
            //lblTest.Text += key + " " + tempList[key] + "units";

            //Check if unitQuantity exceed storage level
            if (((Convert.ToInt32(tempList[key])) * packagesNeeded) > totalUnit)
            {
                //Get the label control in gridview
                foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
                {
                    Panel pnl = item.FindControl("pBody1") as Panel;
                    GridView gv = pnl.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
                    foreach (GridViewRow gr in gv.Rows)
                    {
                        //Compare the key with the data key of the current row
                        if (key == gv.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString())
                        {
                            //Display the insufficient message
                            Label lblCheckAmount = gr.FindControl("lblCheckAmount") as Label;
                            lblCheckAmount.Text = "Insufficient amount";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                distSPUItemList.Add(key, tempList[key]);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I button on click, I get the validated list which is distSPUItemList but not tempList:

```
 protected void lbnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Loop thru distSPUItemList. key as prodID, distSPUItemList.Keys as quantity
        foreach (string key in distSPUItemList.Keys)
        {
            lblTest.Text += key + " " + distSPUItemList[key] + "units";
        }
    }
```

However, at my lblTest there, there is nothing stored in the list. I do not want to store the validated one in tempList because tempList is just contain all the rows that were marked checked. I wonder why is it so. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tempList` and `distSPUItemList` variables will always be empty when `lbnConfirm_Click` is executed, so you need to store them in ViewState to persist their values between postbacks.

Try this code:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> tempList
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["tempList"] == null)
        {
            return new Dictionary<string,string>();
        }
        else
        {
            return (Dictionary<string, string>)ViewState["tempList"];
        }
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["tempList"] = value;
    }
}

private Dictionary<string, string> distSPUItemList
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["distSPUItemList"] == null)
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }
        else
        {
            return (Dictionary<string, string>)ViewState["distSPUItemList"];
        }
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["distSPUItemList"] = value;
    }
}

protected void tbQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tempList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    distSPUItemList = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 

    string quantity = "", prodID = "";
    int packagesNeeded = 0, totalUnit = 0;

    //Get the total packages needed for this distribution
    packagesNeeded = prodPackBLL.getPackagesNeededByDistributionID(distributionID);

    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Panel pnl = item.FindControl("pBody1") as Panel;
            GridView gv = pnl.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
            foreach (GridViewRow gr in gv.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("cbCheckRow");
                if (cb.Checked)
                {
                    //Clear label error message
                    Label lblCheckAmount = gr.FindControl("lblCheckAmount") as Label;
                    lblCheckAmount.Text = "";

                    //Get the productID which set as DataKeyNames and unit quantity from selected row index
                    prodID = gv.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

                    var tbQuantity = gr.FindControl("tbQuantity") as TextBox;
                    if (tbQuantity != null)
                    {
                        quantity = tbQuantity.Text;
                    }

                    //Add both objects into Dictionary
                    tempList.Add(prodID, quantity);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Loop thru tempList. key as prodID, tempList.Keys as quantity
    foreach (string key in tempList.Keys)
    {
        //Get total unit of each products
        totalUnit = prodPackBLL.getTotalProductUnit(key);
        //lblTest.Text += key + " " + tempList[key] + "units";

        //Check if unitQuantity exceed storage level
        if (((Convert.ToInt32(tempList[key])) * packagesNeeded) > totalUnit)
        {
            //Get the label control in gridview
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
            {
                Panel pnl = item.FindControl("pBody1") as Panel;
                GridView gv = pnl.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
                foreach (GridViewRow gr in gv.Rows)
                {
                    //Compare the key with the data key of the current row
                    if (key == gv.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString())
                    {
                        //Display the insufficient message
                        Label lblCheckAmount = gr.FindControl("lblCheckAmount") as Label;
                        lblCheckAmount.Text = "Insufficient amount";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            distSPUItemList.Add(key, tempList[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you click the button without changing any of the textbox values, so both tempList and distSPUItemList are still empty when lbnConfirm_Click is executed. Can you confirm if that's the case?

Comment: Oh ya sorry my mistakes. So basically the dictionary list will become empty when isPostBack so we need a viewState to persist the items inside?

Comment: Yes exactly, and if you want to persist the items without changing the textbox values, then you need to do the same looping from tbQuantity_TextChanged in lbnConfirm_Click

Comment: Okay noted. Thanks a lot. But just to ask, do you know about LINQ query? because I am having problem to retrieve something using LINQ query

Comment: Yes I do, you can post a new question and I'll try to answer, or somebody else will if I can't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832772/retrieve-variable-from-linq-query Here is it.