# Retrieve variable from LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I am having problem when trying to retrieve something from LINQ query. I got a prodList which store all the product records. And another list is distSPUItemList which store the record distributed item records. Here is the codes:

```
//Get list of products based on category and bind data to grid view
prodList = prodPackBLL.getAllProductByCategory(category);
gv.DataSource = prodList;
gv.DataBind();

//Mark checkbox checked for products included in standard packing list
var SPUItemList = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();
SPUItemList = packBLL.getAllSPUItemByDistributionID(distributionID);

//LINQ query to compare lists of objects finding ProductPacking 
//objects whose name property are equal to the items in SPUItemList
var available = from a in prodList
                // perform an inner-join between prodList and SPUItemList only
                // (x => x.name == a.name) compares b.name to a.name, this is 
                // specifically what enforces that names match
                from b in SPUItemList.Where(x => x.name == a.name)
                // after inner joining is done, only select objects from prodList
                select a;

//Iterate the gridview rows
GridView gvForCheckBox = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvForCheckBox.Rows)
{
    if (available.Where(x => x.name == gr.Cells[1].Text).Any())
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("cbCheckRow");
        cb.Checked = true;
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)gr.Cells[3].FindControl("tbQuantity");
        //From here retrieve name and pass it to data access layer to perform SQL
        //Display unitQuantity if name match. If not default text set to 0
    }
}
```

So basically what I am trying to do is `from if (available.Where(x => x.name == gr.Cells[1].Text).Any()){}`, if the name is match, I mark the checkBox checked.
At the same time, I need to get the `unitQuantity` to be packed based on the `productName` from database. But I have no idea how to retrieve the name out of the LINQ query.

Sorry for my poor explanation and thanks in advance.

Edited Portion:

```
 string name = gr.Cells[1].Text;
                            int productQuantity = packBLL.getProductQuantityByName(name);
                            TextBox tb = (TextBox)gr.Cells[3].FindControl("tbQuantity");
                            tb.Text = productQuantity.ToString();
```

It works with this. First, I get the name by specifying the column and then I perform some other Sql statement

Comment: you're not really using b anywhere, and some extra explanation might be useful as well :)

Comment: is there any relation between Product table and SPUItem table?

Comment: SPUItem link to ProductVariant by productVariantID, and ProductVariant link to Product by productID

Comment: Thanks alot. I'd fixed that although I don't think my solution is the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand what you are actually after, you can try to change inside of the `foreach` loop to:

```
var rowData = available.Where(x => x.name == gr.Cells[1].Text).FirstOrDefault();
//if rowData == null, means no matching data in `available` variable
if (rowData != null)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("cbCheckRow");
    cb.Checked = true;
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)gr.Cells[3].FindControl("tbQuantity");
    //example on how to get current name
    var name = rowData.name;
}
```

Comment: I'd got another solution as edited portion. First, I get the name by specifying the column then perform some sql statement by name. Thanks a lot!